How to identify the same date and last month date from prior year based on the most recent date for current year in the table in SQL?
I am trying to summarize the overall profit and transactions results for Name and id grouped by new fields on Amazon Redshift. Data Example is provided below:
Table Data Example
After execution, I would like to show data for each person based on three fields highlighted in yellow.

First Field should show the result for the user for most recent date
in the table
Second Field should show the result for the last month
of prior year
Third Field should have the summation of profit for
same date prior year

Output for one of the user
Sample Code Example:
*Select Id, Name,
sum (CASE when date = '9/1/2024' then profit) as profit_CYR,
sum (CASE when date = '12/1/2023' then profit) as profit_last_year,
sum (CASE when date = '9/1/2023' then profit) as profit_last_year_to_date
from table*

I just don't want to use the dates hard coded.

Don't ever post text data as screenshots on Stack Overflow.  If you want a a good anser, build a DB Fiddle on one of the many db fiddle websites available.  We can't help with queries without complete table definitions and sample data, and a DB Fiddle is a great way to provide that

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And include your current query attempt.

is this for redshift or mysql?  it isn't going to be the same for both

not clear if you mean the most recent date in the table for the user or the most recent date in the table for any user

@ysth : This is for redshift

@ysth : most recent date in the table for any user

hi I think you can use date functions to determine these values based on the current date.
SELECT 
id, name,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date <= current_date) THEN profit ELSE 0 END) AS profit_CYR,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1 year') THEN profit ELSE 0 END) AS profit_last_year,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = current_date - interval '1 year' THEN profit ELSE 0 END) AS profit_last_year_to_date 
FROM table GROUP BY  id,name;


Hey thanks for the response.
I cannot use the current_date in the query block and need to use the date field provided in the table to conclude on the most recent date so that it can be used for calculating profit_last_year, profit_last_year_to_date

I think for above code shared profit_last_year and and profit_last_year_to_date will show results for 09/01/2023 based on max_date i.e.09/01/2024. But I was looking to for profit_last year as 12/01/2023 and profit_last_year_to_date as 09/01/2023
